# jquery image width and height not working on IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, explorer, document-ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#aspnetForm img").load(function () {
             $(this).width(64);
             $(this).height(64);
         });
     });
</script>

 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt="" runat="server" class="pic" style="cursor:pointer" src='<%# StripHTML(Eval("cat_img").ToString()) %>'  />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

It is working in Chrome, but not on IE. Please help me. My image is `<p> <img src=....>` html tag in database. I cleared striphtml method.

Comment: this links will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form img").css({"height":"64px","width":"64px"});
});
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devWaleed/6eas3/4/

Comment: this should also work, but ".each()" method is slower, should avoid it if you can

Comment: or simply use a css no javascript ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Images aren't yet loaded on `ready` event use `$(window).load()` instead
On `ready` only the DOM structure is loaded but not the real images.
It's like you're having the `img` tag but not the file yet

---

OK your problem is totally different, you're looking for this, my mistake
You just want to iterate some images and make them 64x64 that should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aspnetForm img").each(function () {
         $(this).width(64).height(64);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aspnetForm img").each(function () {
        $(this).css({width:64+'px',height:64+'px'});
    });
});
```

If you want to get the width of each image you should wait for the img to load

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     var width, height;
     $("#aspnetForm img").each(function () {
         width = $(this).width();
         height = $(this).height();
         //store the current img width or height or do whatever
     });
 });
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#aspnetForm img").load(function () {
             $(this).width(64);
             $(this).height(64);
         });
     });
</script>

Comment: `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()` or you can still put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` if some closure logic.
Just make sure that the logic regarding images size is inside `$(window).load(function(){....})`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).ready(function () {

         $("#aspnetForm img").load(function () {
             $(this).width(64);
             $(this).height(64);
         });
     });
</script>   replace documen.ready to window.load chore not working too..:(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.load()`, it's deprecated.

Try this, should work for all browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aspnetForm img').css('width', '64px')
                        .css('height', '64px');
});
```

Comment: They deprecated that ,too that is a surprise. OK luckily there's still `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Reference:http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aspnetForm img").load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Here is another way to do this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hS8ev/)**

```
function imageSize(img){
   var theImage = new Image();
   theImage.src = img.attr('src');
   var imgwidth = $(img).width();
   var imgheight = $(img).height();

   alert(imgwidth);
   alert(imgheight);
}

$('img').each(function(){
    var imgsrc = jQuery(this);
    imageSize(imgsrc);
});
```

Comment: That `load` event img bind won't work in some browsers like some versions of Opera 11,12 for instance. Also what happens if the images are a few